# how to maintain angular modules after splitting and publish on npm

Tags: angular, git, npm

I'm working on an angular app. In order to reuse and avoid copy pasting most of the components and services in an other app. I splited the app into modules and published them on a private npm and git server.

Now that's all done I'm wondering how to work on those modules. I face multiple issues regarding this point.
First they can't work by themself most of them require strong authentification and permission in order to get datas.
Each module is now on a git repo.

Should I create a meta project without source versioning using those versionned modules without npm install ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you can benefit from having a monorepo.

Have you tried checking - [Nrwl Extensions](https://github.com/nrwl/nx) ?

They built a solution for just that - sharing the same modules with different apps.

The difference is, is that they're all in one git repository, but you can still publish everything as different npm packages.

Comment: It's a great solution to my problem but I can see some downsides correct me if I'm wrong. If I make a breaking change to a shared lib I have to update all the apps who uses them because Nx do not work with version. A new dev or a trainee will have access in read/write upon all the Nx workspace.

Comment: of course there are downsides (like every solution).
Though, I know they have restriction you could put on dependencies between modules, that might help to avoid silly mistakes as well.